# find the maximum possible ones

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a string of 0's and 1's

Now I want to change 0 to 1 only if adjacent elements for that 0 are not 1'string. Find the maximum ones possible after doing this operation.

**Example:**

```
110011000001 is the input string
```

**Option 1:**

I can change position 8 and position 10 from 0 to 1 to make the string: 110011010101, here there are 7 ones

**Option 2:**

Another way is to change position 9 from 0 to 1, to make the string: 110011001001, here there are 6 ones.

```
So the maximum between 6 and 7 is 7. So the result is 7.
```

Here is my code, I am able to find only one possible way here:

```
int process(String s) {
    char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
    int n = ch.length;
    for(int i=1; i<n-1; i++) {
        char e = ch[i];
        if(e == '0' && ch[i-1] != '1' && ch[i+1] != '1') {
            ch[i] = '1';
        }
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(char c : ch) {
        if(c == '1') count++;
    }   
    return count;
}
```

How to get the maximum possible ones here.

Comment: You are changing it in place, this means that your array is being modified so some elements that may have been 0 are now 1s so your possible count is lower.  If you want to find the actual count, don't modify the original array that you are checking instead keep a marker and modify it later on once all of your conditions are checked..

Comment: Your example indicates you change one character at a time, rather than changing characters simultaneously.  I just want to confirm that interpretation is correct.

Comment: @learner You never reverted back with any of the answers you received to most of your questions. What makes you think devs will be encouraged to help you this time?

Comment: @nice_dev, I am trying to check with different test cases before commenting for them, I reverted to most of my posts.

Comment: @James, we have to change only 0's to 1's only if there are no adjacent 1's for that zero. That is the only condition.

Comment: @user16320675, if position 8 is changed to 1 then we cannot have another 1 at position 9 as position 8 is already modified.

Comment: @learner I don't see that though.

Comment: @user16320675 I have updated my post with example and possible options for that example

Comment: Off topic: If the simultaneous interpretation applied, you could change three zeros to ones.  But, that would be a less interesting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Notice that if the 0's are surrounded by 1's, you only need `2n + 1`
   adjacent 0's in order to add `n` 1's. In order to add one 1, you
   need at least three 0's: `2*1+1=3`. In order to add two 1's, you
   need at least five 0's: `2*2+1=5`. Since the number of 0's can be
   described as, `Z >= 2n + 1`, we can instead solve for *n*. We get `n <= (Z - 1) / 2`. Thus, when surrounded by 1's, each group of 0's can
   fit `n=floor((Z-1)/2)`; we floor the value since we can't add half of a 1.
2. For groups of 0's only bounded by a 1 on a single side, we notice
   that we need at least `2n` 0's in order to add `n` 1's. Again, we
   rearrange the equation `Z >= 2n` in order to get `n <= Z / 2`. Thus,
   for groups bounded by a single 1, `n=floor(Z/2)`.
3. For our last case, with a string of all 0's, we see that `Z >= 2n - 1`. So, `n <= (Z + 1) / 2`, or for our purposes `floor((Z+1)/2)`.

Least common will be category 3. This will only happen if there are no 1's. If this is the case, you cannot have anything from category 1 or 2 -- **so check this category first**.
Second most common will be category 2. This happens when the beginning OR end of the string is a 0, but there are 1's elsewhere. Check this category second because you can fit more 1's with it than with the formula for the first case. Depending on your solution, you may have to keep track of the places you've already checked before moving on to using case 1 by using a substring of the original.
Most cases will land in category 1, since (in a random combination of 1's and 0's) most groups of 0's will be surrounded by 1's.

Your answer only checks the first case. Using these three cases together will give you the number of 1's that you can add to the string. Add this to the number of 1's you had originally and you'll have your answer.

Edited for clarity.

Comment: Adding "working code" is generally discouraged for such homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

- Count all existing ones as they are going to be a part of the answer.
- To convert 0 to 1, count all zeroes between two ones.

  - If string is 100001, you have total 4 zeroes in between. Here let us leave boundary zeroes as we can't change them as they are adjacent to 1. So, now we are left with 2 zeroes in the middle out of which we can place only in 1 of them.
  - So count is just ceil(all valid zeroes / 2).

    - If you have a string like 00001, here you can place 2 ones excluding that boundary 0 adjacent to 1. So, count is ceil(3/2) which is 2. Your string would look like 10101.
- Final answer is just step 1 + step 2.